# Conversão de Datas para o banco de dados Mysql

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Olá!

Bem, Estou utilizando o xhtml e primefaces.

Na minha pagina xhtml, tenho um campo para data e uso o conversor para salvar no banco de dados, eu tenho um problema com o dia.

Se quero salvar 30/04/1989

No banco de dados salva 1989/04/29

Meu campo é do tipo Date.

```
public class Funcionario {
    private Long id;
    private String nomeUsuario;
    private String senha;
    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    private Date data;
    private Cargo funcao = new Cargo();
    private Restricao restricao = new Restricao();

    //getters e setters omitidos
}
```

Qualquer data, sempre é gravada com um dia a menos.

Na minha pagina xhtml estou utilizando um converter do jsf.

```
<p:outputLabel for="data" value="Nascimento" />
    <p:inputMask id="data" mask="99/99/9999" placeholder="Dia/Mês/Ano"
     value="#{BeanFuncionario.funcionario.data}"
     requiredMessage="Campo data de nascimente é obrigatório."
     required="true">

       <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.DateTime" />
   </p:inputMask>
```

No entando, fiz uns teste em de inserção Utilizando uma classe com jUnit e eu note que:

```
   @Test
public void salvar(){

    CargoDAO cargo = new CargoDAO();
    RestricaoDAO restricao = new RestricaoDAO();

    //Cargos e retricoes
    List<Cargo> lista = cargo.listar();
    List<Restricao> lista2 = restricao.listar();


    //CRIA UM USUARIO
    Funcionario usuario = new Funcionario();
    usuario.setNomeUsuario("jhimmyliborio");
    usuario.setSenha("s2mm1s");
    usuario.setNome("TESTE DE INCLUSAO 1");
    usuario.setCpf("88888888888");

    // DEFININDO DATA
    Date data = new Date("1989/04/30");
    usuario.setData(data);

    //DEFINE FUNCAO E RESTRICAO
    usuario.setFuncao(lista.get(1));
    usuario.setRestricao(lista2.get(1));

    // SALVAR
    FuncionarioDAO udao = new FuncionarioDAO();
    udao.salvar(usuario);
}
```

Se uso o Date para definir a data, tudo ocorre bem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se uso o Calendar para definir a data, acabo tendo probelmas com o mês. ele é incrementado +1;

30/04/1989 - >> 1989/05/30

```
    @Test
public void salvar(){


    CargoDAO cargo = new CargoDAO();
    RestricaoDAO restricao = new RestricaoDAO();

    //Cargos e retricoes
    List<Cargo> lista = cargo.listar();
    List<Restricao> lista2 = restricao.listar();


    //CRIA UM USUARIO
    Funcionario usuario = new Funcionario();
    usuario.setNomeUsuario("liborioJhimmy");
    usuario.setSenha("s2mm1s");
    usuario.setNome("TESTE DE INCLUSAO 2");
    usuario.setCpf("99999999999");

    // DEFININDO DATA
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(1989, 04, 30);
    Date data = c.getTime();
    usuario.setData(data);

    //DEFINE FUNCAO E RESTRICAO
    usuario.setFuncao(lista.get(1));
    usuario.setRestricao(lista2.get(1));

    // SALVAR
    FuncionarioDAO udao = new FuncionarioDAO();
    udao.salvar(usuario);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa aqui é meu DAO.

```
   public void salvar(Funcionario user) {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append(" INSERT INTO funcionario ");
    sql.append("(nome_usuario, senha, nome, cpf, nascimento, cargo_id) ");
    sql.append("VALUES (lower(?),lower(?),lower(?),lower(?), ?,lower(?)) ");

    try (Connection conexao = new Conexao().getConexao()) {
        PreparedStatement pstm = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        pstm.setString(1, user.getNomeUsuario());
        pstm.setString(2, user.getSenha());
        pstm.setString(3, user.getNome());
        pstm.setString(4, user.getCpf());
        pstm.setDate(5, new Date(user.getData().getTime()));
        pstm.setLong(6, user.getFuncao().getId());

        pstm.executeUpdate();
        //Mensagens.msgSucesso("Novo usuário salvo", user.getNomeUsuario());
        pstm.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Mensagens.msgErro("Erro", e.getMessage().toString());
    }
```

Eu não sei como o converter do jsf se comporta, Já criei minha prorpia classe que converte a entrada da pagina do usuário para o banco. Porém da um erro de conversão. Não foi possível converter uma String para Date.

```
    public static void dataBanco(Funcionario funcionario){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    String banco = sdf.format(funcionario.getData());
    Date data;
    try {
        data = sdf.parse(banco);
        funcionario.setData(data);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Poderia definir melhor a sua pergunta? Pois vejo várias dúvidas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você relata dois problemas: um com a data usando componentes primefaces (que é inocente, neste caso particular, pois este comportamento é do JSF em si) e um usando a classe `Calendar`.

### Problema com data no JSF

O **JSF** trata de converter o horário informado para **GMT**. O fuso horário de Brasília é **GMT-3**. Ou seja, o JSF está diminuindo 3 horas da data informada, *30/04/1989* (meia-noite), resultando no dia anterior.

Você pode informar o *time zone* desejado (GMT-3) para o conversor de datas. No seu código, ficaria assim:

```
<p:inputMask id="data" mask="99/99/9999" placeholder="Dia/Mês/Ano"
     value="#{BeanFuncionario.funcionario.data}"
     requiredMessage="Campo data de nascimente é obrigatório."
     required="true">

    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="GMT-3"/>
</p:inputMask>
```

Ou pode configurar seu aplicativo para que o JSF sempre utilize o GMT local do sistema (arquivo **web.xml**):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>
            javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE
    </param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

### Problema com data considerando múltiplos fuso horários no JSF

A primeira solução que apresentei acima se aplica caso o seu sistema seja usado apenas no Brail, e a segunda solução se aplica bem caso o seu sistema seja usado em um país apenas (independentemente de qual).

Se o seu sistema precisa ser compartilhado por usuários em diferentes fuso horários, e dependendo da necessidade, você pode ter que fazer um tratamento mais complexo de data e hora, como por exemplo deixando o JSF converter a data para GMT e salvar também o GMT do usuário. Mas a solução ideal vai depender dos seus requisitos.

### Problema com data usando a classe Calendar

O método `set` de um objeto `Calendar` espera que o mês esteja indexado em zero (pois é...). De modo que este código:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(1989, 04, 30);
Date data = c.getTime();
System.out.println(data.toString());
```

Produz a seguinte saída:

`Tue May 30 10:27:33 BRT 1989`

Ou seja, 30 de maio e não 30 de abril como você espera.

Você teria que setar `3` para abril. Ou usar as constantes da classe `Calendar`:

`c.set(1989, Calendar.APRIL, 30);`

Comment: Entao eu teria que pegar a String digitada pelo usuário lá no xhtml. Converter para data e manipular com o Calendar e diminuir o mês,  é isso?

Comment: @user3096136 Atualizei minha resposta para tratar também o problema com a data no JSF; que parece ser o problema principal enquanto o problema com o Calendar parece ser apenas uma investigação.

Comment: Muito bem explicado Caffé, Obrigado pela ajuda!