# Trabalhando com Datas em JavaWeb

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, mvc, tdd

Olá, estou fazendo um projeto que Gerencia todos os projetos da minha empresa, estou utilizando *Hibernate, JavaWeb, primefaces, TDD e padrão MVC*.

Minha entidade está moldada assim para variáveis de data:

```
 @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "dataInicio_projeto", nullable = false)
    private Date dataInicio;
```

e Usei isso no TDD para testar ela:

```
projeto1.setDataInicio(new Date());
```

Preciso saber como faço na parte visual(JSF) do projeto para enviar a data de escolha do usuário para o banco, pois o banco se modela de acordo com a entidade (fiz a engenharia reversa).

Um amigo me disse para usar variavel 'Calendar' pois é uma melhoria da 'Date', não sei o que fazer. Preciso de ajuda...

Comment: E como está seu `JSF`? Esse [post](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38933/convers%C3%A3o-de-datas-para-o-banco-de-dados-mysql) talvez possa te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O JSF é um framework component base, ou seja, ele trabalha com componentes na view. Normalmente utiliza-se alguma biblioteca de componentes que amplia a possibilidade de componentes e facilita o desenvolvimento. 
Uma muito conhecida é o [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/) 
Para fazer uma uma view com um pequeno formulário que dentre outras coisas receberia uma data você precisa de um controller(classe java que vai controlar a sua view) e a view propriamente dita(onde no jsf utliza-se páginas .xhtml).

Segue um exemplo de view:

```
<h:form id="form">
 <p:outputLabel for="datetime" value="Datetime:" />
        <p:calendar id="datetime" value="#{testeController.data}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
 <p:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{testController.salvar}" />
</h:form>
```

E o controller para gerenciar a mesma:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScope
public class TesteController{

private Date data;

 public Date getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data date) {
        this.data = date;
    }

 public void salvar(){
    System.out.println("Data inserida: " + this.data);
}


}
```

A partir deste ponto no método salvar você tem que fazer a lógica para salvar no banco de dados. Não entrarei em detalhes aqui sobre ela porque é um assunto bem extenso, você encontrará mais informações neste link:
[Introdução ao JPA](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/uma-introducao-pratica-ao-jpa-com-hibernate/)

Comment: Ok, entendi, está funcionando, e como faço para formatar a data na hora de visualizar ? Por exemplo não quero utilizar os minutos e horas, quero apenas a data.

Estou mostrando a data assim:

<h:outputText value="#{projeto.dataInicio}"/>

Comment: Você pode usar um converter para isso, para datas o jsf já tem um converter padrão, faça da seguinte maneira:
`<h:outputText value="#{projeto.dataInicio}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-mm-yyyy" />
</h:outputText>`